# when to use pseudo-classes and when to use pseudo-elements selectors in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

what i don't understand about these concepts is when should i use a pseudo-class selector like `:before` or `:first-child` and when to use a pseudo-element selector like `::before`.

Comment: Note: CSS3 introduced the ::before notation (with two colons) to distinguish pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept :before, introduced in CSS2. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before#syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single colon syntax is an older implementation. In general, there are pseudo-elements `::` & pseudo-classes `:`, and they are not identical. In this case though, browsers still support the outdated single-colon syntax.

This means that in your example with `:before`/`::before`, it will not make a difference to the outcome, but in general you should use the double colon syntax, because before & after are pseudo-elements, not pseudo-classes.

Read [more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements#what_is_a_pseudo-element).

Answer (score 0):

The **::before** selector inserts something before the content of each selected element(s).

Use the content property to specify the content to insert.

```
/* CSS3 syntax */
::before

/* CSS2 syntax */
:before
```

More info [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)